# Convergence of a Generalized Taylor Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, closed-form

I have been playing around with the fundamental theorem of calculus:

Starting with
$$f(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x f'(t_1) \mathrm{d}t_1, \tag{1}$$

one can apply the FTC again, this time to the derivative, to get

$$f'(t_1)=f'(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{t_1} f''(t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2. \tag{2}$$

Substituting $(2)$ in $(1)$ gives

$$f(x)=f(x_0) + f'(x_0) (x-x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_0}^{t_1} f''(t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2\, \mathrm{d}t_1.$$

This is one way to get the classical Taylor expansion, with the remainder term here in iterated integral form.

---

I wondered what would happen if different "centers" are used at every step. For example, replacing Equation $(2)$ with
$$f'(t_1) = f'(x_1)+ \int_{x_1}^{t_1} f''(t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2,  $$
gives

$$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_1)(x-x_0)+\int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_1}^{t_1} f''(t_2) \mathrm{d}t_2 \, \mathrm{d} t_1. $$

What I got after $n$ steps was

$$f(x)=P_n(x;x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n)+R_n(x;x_0,x_1,\dots,x_n),$$
where

$$P_n(x;x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n})=\sum_{k=0}^n f^{(k)}(x_k) \int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_1}^{t_1} \cdots \int_{x_{k-1}}^{t_{k-1}} \mathrm{d}t_k \, \cdots \mathrm{d}t_2 \, \mathrm{d} t_1, $$

and

$$R_n(x;x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{n}) = \int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_1}^{t_1} \cdots \int_{x_{n-1}}^{t_{n-1}} \int_{x_n}^{t_n} f^{(n+1)}(t_{n+1}) \mathrm{d}t_{n+1}\,\mathrm{d}t_n \, \cdots \mathrm{d}t_2 \, \mathrm{d} t_1.$$

Some of the low-order polynomials are:

$$\begin{align}
P_0 &= f(x_0), \\
P_1 &= f(x_0)+f'(x_1)(x-x_0), \\
P_2 &= f(x_0)+f'(x_1)(x-x_0)+ \frac{f''(x_2)}{2}(x - x_0) (x + x_0 - 2 x_1),\\
P_3 &= P_2+ \frac{f'''(x_3)}{6} (x-x_0) \left(x^2-3 x_1^2+x_0 \left(x+x_0\right)-3 \left(x+x_0-2 x_1\right) x_2 \right).
\end{align} $$

**My questions are:**

1. Do the multivariate polynomials $\int_{x_0}^x \int_{x_1}^{t_1} \cdots \int_{x_{k-1}}^{t_{k-1}} \mathrm{d}t_k \, \cdots \mathrm{d}t_2 \, \mathrm{d} t_1$ have a closed form?
2. Is this expansion well-known?
3. Aside from polynomials, and analytic functions where $x_0=x_1=\dots$ , are there criteria for which an infinite series expansion exists? (that is $\lim_{n\to \infty} R_n =0 $.)

Thanks.